# psycopg2 not compatible with postgres14 Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I did a brew update the other day that updated my postgres version from 13 to 14 which caused me to get this error with psycopg2

`psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function array_cat(anyarray, anyarray) does not exist`

It took me a while to figure out what was going on but downgrading to postgres@13 fixed the issue. I couldn't find any information on what versions of postgres psycopg2 is compatible with but it sure seems like it doesn't work with postgres@14 can anyone confirm this or point me to supported versions in psycopg2?

Comment: I just tried running a small connect/create table/insert/select session against a PG14 database using an old psycopg2 I had lying around, and that worked just fine. Could you please provide the full traceback, and a minimal example that triggers the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This mailing list thread](https://postgrespro.com/list/id/3266664.1633045937@sss.pgh.pa.us) quotes the [Postgresql 14 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/) which say

> User-defined objects that reference certain built-in array functions along with their argument types must be recreated (Tom Lane)

> Specifically, array_append(), array_prepend(), array_cat(), array_position(), array_positions(), array_remove(), array_replace(), and width_bucket() used to take anyarray arguments but now take anycompatiblearray. Therefore, user-defined objects like aggregates and operators that reference those array function signatures must be dropped before upgrading, and recreated once the upgrade completes.

So if you have any user-defined functions that reference array_cat, that sounds like it.

Comment: That is definitely whats going on, I have a function using array_cat with the anyarray type.